# adding rich snippets from schema.org for a joomla! site?

Tags: joomla, schema.org

I am not sure how to add markup for my joomla! site.  Can anyone tell me how to use schema.org rich snippets?

Comment: There was a good presentation on this at the Joomla World Conference you can find the video here.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGQLpLmuQ60&list=PL0Lg2fzcJu1Q8xkz8FhTwo8pyuskUgLhJ&index=8

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for Joomla to add options on the default editor

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/meta-data/19961

Answer (score 0):

In case you need it for VirtueMart products, there is this plugin:

http://www.easyjoomla.org/paid-extensions/rich-snippets-for-virtuemart